# Free energy Landau developpment for superconductor : why do we limit ourselves to order 4 in $\psi$

Tags: thermodynamics, superconductivity

In superconductivity, for a phase transition in temperature (not in magnetic field), we have an order parameter describing it.

We call it $\psi$ and it is a complex number.

We do a Taylor expansion of the free energy like this :

$$ f_s(T)=f_n(T)+a(T) |\Psi|^2+ \frac{1}{2} b(T) |\Psi|^4+...$$

Where $f_n(T)$ is the free energy of the normal phase.

At equilibrium, the free energy is minimum. And if we find $f_s<f_n$ it means that the superconducting phase is more stable.

We want that for $T<Tc$ it is the case, so we choose the $a(T)$ and $b(T)$ coefficient to assure ourselves of the existence of a minimum lower than $f_n$ for $T<Tc$.

In my example we took : $a(T)=\alpha (T-T_c)$, $b(T)=b$. It ensures us the existence of this minimum below $T_c$ but not above.

And the determination of the value of this minimum (in fact the difference $f_s-f_n$) is usefull to determine the critical magnetic field $H_c$ for example.

What I don't understand is our limitation to $|\Psi|^4$ in the developpment. Indeed we could imagine, by taking higher power in $|\Psi|$,  lower minimum so different values of $f_s-f_n$ **and thus others values for $H_c$ which makes no sense**.

Comment: As usual with perturbation expansion, the higher orders are weaker and weaker. One keeps the 6-th order term when the 4-th order disappears. This is a generic prescription. You could have kept the 1-st or 3-rd orders as well if for symmetry reason they can not be killed.

Comment: I understand what you say but I don't totally agree. Imagine my free energy is a polynomial function $f(x)=a_0+a_1x^2+a_2x^4+a_3x^6+a_4x^8$. If we stop at order $4$ we could have a global minimum extremely different than if we stop at order $8$. It depends on the values of the $ai$ coefficient. This is what I don't get.

Comment: Take your polynomials, and imposes $a_{0}\gg a_{1}\gg a_{2}\gg a_{3}\gg\cdots$. Truncating the polynomials at fourth order (and suppose the odd powers are forbidden by symmetry considerations), you get the correct minimum at fourth-order. Truncating at 6-th order, you get perturbation of the previous minimum. Not something *extremely different*. Of course you must believe that the theory is perturbative, something one sometimes doesn't know.

Comment: In fact that was exactly my question ! How **do we know** we have indeed a perturbative developpment of the free energy of the superconductive phase ? Why the coefficient of the free energy of the superconducting phase verifies $a_{n+1} << a_n$ ? Is it an assumption ? Because it is not obvious at all for me.

Comment: Because you're close to the second order phase transition, which is a continuous phase transition, so the order parameter is small. In your notation, $\Psi\ll 1$. Otherwise the Landau's expansion doesn't work. So in a way the next-order coefficient must be small compared to the previous order one.

Comment: For superconductivity, you can calculate the coefficients at any order using the BCS mean-field approximation. You realise that the expansion is perturbative. If I remember correctly, the coefficients are in the form of $a_{k}\sim\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\left(t+n+1/2\right)^{k}}$, with $t\sim T/T_{c}-1$, and you can check that they decay faster and faster (as $t^{-\left(k-1\right)}$) for large $t$. This is done in textbooks on superconductivity. I may have done mistake with the exponents.

Comment: I agree that I'm close to the transition so $\psi <<1$.  But I don't get how the fact that $\psi<<1$ implicates that my coefficients $a_i$ will fastly decrease and thus that I have a perturbative developpment ? Is it more something like : as $\psi$ is small I have to look for the first minimum (the other are "too far" and the approximation is wrong there). So I can limit myself to order 2 ? Thank you for the last comment, I keep it in mind but as I just learned basics of BCS I didn't go that far and I would like to understand Landau without this BCS point of view :)

Comment: Well, if you agree that $\Psi\ll 1$ then when you find $\Psi^{2} = -a_{1}/2a_{2}$ for the ground state, this should be small for consistency, so at least ratios of the coefficients must be small. In fact that's all you need to make a perturbative expansion.